# Pass in isolated scope object into angular custom directive template?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use an object in an angular template in a custom directive. [Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/RmG1seAcQOxaDm0iEol9?p=preview) a plunker to explain what kind of trouble I'm having.

After some fiddling around i came to the conclusion that i need to use `scope: {address: '='}` in order to pass in an object into the directive's template instead of `scope: {street: '@'}` which is what i used for the street value. However it is throwing a parsing error, and not displaying the address's country correctly. Can someone help explain what I'm doing wrong here? I've looked at dozens of examples but can't quite figure out how to fix it.

[Here's a simple working example of what i'm trying to achieve but for some reason I can't replicate this](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/fhvd9/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double braces around your object.

```
<address-b address="user.address"></address-b>
```